# Text area is not working

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in my form

```
<input style="height:80px;width:232px;font-size:20px" maxlength="250" name="address" type="text" value="<?php echo $address;?>" />
```

It works fine and value in $address is showing in the text field. But I need to replace the text field to text area.For that I wrote the following code,

```
 <textarea style="height:80px;width:232px;font-size:20px" maxlength="250" name="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>" ></textarea>
```

But this code shows no values. Please help me.

Comment: Guys, don't you use any IDE that tells you "Attribute 'value' for textarea is not allowed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below:

```
<textarea style="height:80px;width:232px;font-size:20px" maxlength="250" name="address"><?php echo $address;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea is not proper ,  You need to insert your message between the opening and closing tags.

`<textarea><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>`